# How to add mustache email template and send it

Tags: spring-boot, email, kotlin, mustache

Mustache template: `email.mustache`

```
{{subject}}

Hello {{userName}}!
```

The object I will send.

```
data class Email(
        @Email
        val emailAddress: String,
        val subject: String,
        val userName: String,
        val message: String
)
```

My service:

```
@Service
class EmailService {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var javaMailSender: JavaMailSender

    override fun sendEmail(email: Email): Boolean {
        val msg = SimpleMailMessage()
        msg.setTo(email.emailAddress)
        msg.setSubject(email.subject)
        msg.setText(email.message)
        try {
            javaMailSender.send(msg)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

But how can I load my mustache template in this? I imagine I need to parse the mustache template then use that as `msg.setText(parsedTemplate)` -- something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Mustache.java](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java) can do what you need:

```
import com.github.mustachejava.DefaultMustacheFactory
import com.github.mustachejava.Mustache
import java.io.StringWriter

data class Email(
    val subject: String,
    val userName: String
)

fun main() {
    val scopes = mapOf(
        "email" to Email(subject = "Welcome", userName = "J_Strauton")
    )

    val writer = StringWriter()
    val mf = DefaultMustacheFactory()
    val mustache: Mustache = mf.compile("email.mustache")
    mustache.execute(writer, scopes)
    writer.flush()

    val email = writer.toString()
}
```

Your `email.mustache` file could look like this:

```
{{email.subject}}

Hello {{email.userName}}!
```